# how to check for the dirty data on form in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons in my form, save and back.
I am performing check of dirty data on the click of back button in javascript using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$('#formName').form('dirtyDataCheck'); 
});
```

and on the click of save button:

```
var formData = $('#formName').serialize(); 
$.ajax(
{
type: 'POST',
url: CTX_ROOT + '/save.go?' + formData,
blockItem: $('#btnSave'),
success: function()
{
   // on save make dirty data flag false.
   $.dirtyData.isDirty = false;

   // Display message on successful save.
   $.msg.append('save successful');  
}
});
```

But this is not working. the page navigates back without any alert message for dirty data if any of the field's value is changed.

Comment: What's `$.dirtyData`?

Comment: it is the flag set for no check of dirty data if user clicks on save button

Comment: Where is it defined though? Otherwise `$.dirtyData.isDirty` would trigger an error.

Comment: `blockItem: $('#btnSave')`: As far as I know you can't pass a jQuery object as is with ajax (data must be in string format). I bet your ajax call actually breaks and is never executed. Also are you preventing the default behavior of your save button? How's that button set up (anchor or button type submit)?

Comment: button type submit.. if u people think this approach would not work.. what should i do to perform dirty data check

Comment: i have also tried the following script:

    var isDirty = false;
    var msg = 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').change(function(){
        if(!isDirty){
            isDirty = true;
        }
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(isDirty){
            return msg;
        }
    };
    });